# " maven -version" command is not recognized in Git Bash

Tags: bash, git, maven

I am trying to run commands like `maven -version`,`mvn clean install` but get the following error:

```
$ maven -version
bash: maven: command not found
```

I have all the necessary Environment variables and Paths in place.

Comment: Does it work in maven install directory? Please add your environment variables to your question also.

Comment: Its works in the command prompt but not in git bash. My Environment variables are as following.
MAVEN_HOME and path directs to Maven installation folder.
JAVA_HOME and the path directs to the JAVA installation folder.
In the PATH : I have put the path (untill bin folder) for both Maven and jdk.

Comment: Can you please do `echo %PATH%` and `echo $PATH` and paste the results? How long is your PATH? Does the same error appear if you run `mvn -version` in your Maven installation directory on Git Bash?

Comment: The result of echo %PATH% :  `C:\Windows\system32>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\System32\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\;C:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\MO3772\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`
<br>The result of echo $PATH : `$PATH`<br/>

Comment: When I do `mvn -version` in maven installation folder in git bash, it does work.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen . I do not how but I can run maven commands now in git bash in all directories. Thanks for your time and help. The only issue is that, I have to run Git Bash " as administrator" to successfully build my code otherwise the `mvn clean install` fails  with reason "access is denied" .

Answer (score 1):

Set path as below:

export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin:/c/Program\ Files/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin

Answer (score 0):

`mvn -v` or `mvn --version`.

```
Command is not recognized
```

Probably you are in one of the following 2 situations:

You didn't add the Maven to the path (run `ECHO %PATH%` in `cmd` to see if you are in this situation).

Go to the environment variables and click on New… and add:

```
M2_HOME=<your_path>
MAVEN_HOME=%M2_HOME%
MAVEN_BIN=%M2_HOME%\bin
```

Click on Edit… and add the `;%MAVEN_BIN%` at the end of the path
You added it to the path, but you didn't open a new command prompt. Open a new command prompt, because the environment variables are not updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

The solution was to **reinstall maven and jdk** (I used chocolatey so the **paths** were automaticly **deleted and added again**) and simply **restart the computer**.

Good luck to you all <3